# java packages does not exist gradle build fail

Tags: java

[image]

I have added the dependency for apache commons-lang3 as shown in my build.gradle. I tried to rebuild but it still shows this error. What am i doing wrong here? thank you

Comment: What is the ide used?

Comment: The first message indicates that the caches are corrupted. Try File > Invalidate Caches, and then re-build.

Comment: @Ninja, have u found the solution?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are building in ide. Instead of gradle build. Invoke gradle build task with your ide gradle plugin. Or execute gradle build in command line in work space folder
If your ide gradle plugin permits refresh gradle libraries and you will resolve dependencies then build might work